# Selected row to column

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following Table :

[image: MyTable]

but need to select following result ,Also be notice that may items are not fixed!!

[image: Result]

Comment: All you need is a [pivot](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution, continue to N :

```
select distinct f1.parentfk, f2.Quantity  , f3.Quantity, f4.Quantity, f5.Quantity  
from mytable f1
left outer join mytable f2 on f1.parentfk=f2.parentfk and f2.itemfk=1
left outer join mytable f3 on f1.parentfk=f3.parentfk and f3.itemfk=2
left outer join mytable f4 on f1.parentfk=f4.parentfk and f4.itemfk=3
left outer join mytable f5 on f1.parentfk=f5.parentfk and f5.itemfk=4
```

Or try this dynamic query :

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = N'';

SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(itemfk) FROM (SELECT distinct f2.itemfk FROM Mytable f2) AS x;

SET @sql = N'
SELECT j.ParentFk, ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT ParentFk, Quantity, itemfk FROM Mytable
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  Sum(Quantity) FOR itemfk IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';

PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: but it is not specified how many N column it would exists ??!!
and 1,2,3,4 not fixed !!

Comment: no, but you can use a big number of query. Same if you use Pivot instruction you must give a number of column. Then except if you build a dynamic query (in storage procedure by examle), i have not better solution !! ?? May be other person found

Comment: an example to dynamic query https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: There is no other way than dynamic query if you do not know what columns you need.